# Material Design In Xaml - DialogHost positioning

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Just started using MDIX - love it so far. Question: With materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent, is there a way to position the dialog such that it is centered in the app verses over the control that is invoking it?

Comment: You should put the DialogHost as you top-most control - for example as the first control in your MainWindow. The popup it displays content in is limited to the DialogHost control. I strongly recomend you download the [samples](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXaml.Examples) repository and checkout how it's done

Comment: My app is rather involved and uses the aterialDesign:DrawerHost as the container on the window with several buttons that use DialogHosts for additional specific information and processing.  I like the concept but just wish I had additional control of the placement

Comment: The idea is that you can have multiple dialog hosts. If you want to cover the whole window, put the dialog host as a root. If you want to cover smaller control, put it in there. You can specify the DialogHost identifier so that the static invocation will go up the logical tree and find the one with that specific Identifier. You cannot really control the placement or even the size of the dialog (ex if you want it to stretch, you need to [bind width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088234/wpf-materialdesigninxamltoolkit-dialog-expand-to-full-width))

Comment: the samples repo I linked previously shows this nicely